# flutter How to check the size of a growable list growable list

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a scenario, I have a login page on my app when  a user logins in, the app waits for a response from the api, the api response can come in 2 ways. On way with the data as empty or with a growable list. Eg

```
{
    "id": "ea6d156a-ac2e-49b1-b006-1cf2c9092224",
    "auth_token": "token",
    "email": "tester@gmail.com",
    "gender": male,
    "fullname": "tester",
    "contactNo": "08056582232",
    "participants": [
        {
            "participantid": "055556666",
            "dateobirth": "1983-10-12T00:00:00",
            "nextofkinname": "Tester",
            "nextofkinemail": "tester@gmail.com",
            "nextofkinphonenumber": "1234567",
            "gender": "female",
            "contactnumber": "8900000",
            "fullname": "Participant Two",
            "userid": "ea6d156a-ac2e-49b1-b006-1cf2c9092224",
            "schedules": [
                {
                    "id": 74436,
                    "followUpStageId": 1,
                    "windowStart": "2022-01-28T00:00:00",
                    "windowEnd": "2022-01-30T00:00:00",
                    "showUp": 0,
                    "showUpDate": null,
                    "vaxDose": 0,
                    
                }                   
                
            ]
        }
```

or it can come as

```
{
    "id": "afc7e6ff-878a-418b-9a2f-6f7fe2240085",
    "auth_token": "",
    "email": "tester@gmail.com",
    "gender": "male",
    "fullname": "tester",
    "contactNo": "1234567",
    "participants": []
}
```

Am storing the values in a shared preference, and using them in different places in the app.
I want to check if `participants: []` had data if it has data take the user directly to the home screen if is empty the go through the process of adding a participant. How can I check if the size of the participant is zero or not?

this is what I have so far

```
void getLoggedInStatus() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    isLoggedIn = prefs.getBool('isLoggedIn') ?? false;
    gotData = prefs.getString("participants") ??[]; // get the data from prefs
    print(gotData);
    double data = jsonDecode(gotData);// decode and get size
    print(data);
    var token = prefs.get("auth_token") ?? "";
    var url = Uri.parse(Api.PARTICIPANT_SCHEDULER);

    debugPrint("user is logged in: $isLoggedIn");

    if (isLoggedIn) {
      try {
        // try accessing anything from the server
        var response = await http.get(url,
            headers: {"authorization": "Bearer $token"});
        // token expiration check
        // if 401 is not returned, the token is still valid. skip authentication
        if (response.statusCode != 401) {
          if (data.size !=0) { //this doesnt work, it skips the if statements and does nothing
            WADashboardScreen().launch(context); //go to home screen if not empty
          } else {
          WAAddCredentialScreen().launch(context); //add user details if it is empty
          }
        }
      } on SocketException catch (_) {}
    }
  }
```

How am saving to the shared prefs

```
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
var parse = jsonDecode(response.body);
prefs.setBool("isLoggedIn", true);
await prefs.setString('email', parse["email"]);
await prefs.setString('auth_token', parse["auth_token"]);
await prefs.setString('gender', parse["gender"]);
await prefs.setString('participants', (jsonEncode(parse["participants"]))) ;
await prefs.setString('fullname', parse["fullname"]);
await prefs.setString('id', parse["id"]);
```

Have been scratching my head for a while now, how can I check the size or check if participants has data or not and then proceed to the different screens? Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
  var body=json.decode(response.body);
     if(body["participants"].isEmpty){
     ...
  }
```

should help you...

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

In
`await prefs.setString('participants', (jsonEncode(parse["participants"])));`

You are doing two wrong things here.

1. You are encoding & parsing json which you are supposed itself a `String`?
2. You are storing `List<dynamic>` as a `String` which is not the optimal way.

You might want to use other packages to store  `participants`. SharedPreference is not optimal for every use case.